# .NET HBase REST API client library - calling from MVC5 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, hadoop, hbase

Looking at the sample code given on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hbase-tutorial-get-started/#use-the-net-hbase-rest-api-client-library,

I'm trying to connect to HBase from an MVC Controller as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

using Microsoft.HBase.Client;
using org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.protobuf.generated;

namespace MyHBaseTest.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/myhbasetestcontroller")]
    public class MyHBaseTestController : ApiController
    {
        HBaseReader hbase = new HBaseReader();

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult Index()
        {

            string clusterURL = "https://<yourHBaseClusterName>.azurehdinsight.net";
            string hadoopUsername = "<yourHadoopUsername>";
            string hadoopUserPassword = "<yourHadoopUserPassword>";

            // Create a new instance of an HBase client.
            ClusterCredentials creds = new ClusterCredentials(new Uri(clusterURL), hadoopUsername, hadoopUserPassword);
            HBaseClient hbaseClient = new HBaseClient(creds);

            // Retrieve the cluster version
            var version = hbaseClient.GetVersion();
            Console.WriteLine("The HBase cluster version is " + version);

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to view the URL /api/myhbasetestcontroller in my browser when it is run in debug mode, it keeps loading the page forever without throwing any exception or anything in Visual Studio. I have waited for 15-20 minutes but nothing changes.

When I put try to do the same in a console application, it gets the version information in a matter of seconds though:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.HBase.Client;
using org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.protobuf.generated;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string clusterURL = "https://<yourHBaseClusterName>.azurehdinsight.net";
            string hadoopUsername= "<yourHadoopUsername>";
            string hadoopUserPassword = "<yourHadoopUserPassword>";

            // Create a new instance of an HBase client.
            ClusterCredentials creds = new ClusterCredentials(new Uri(clusterURL), hadoopUsername, hadoopUserPassword);
            HBaseClient hbaseClient = new HBaseClient(creds);

            // Retrieve the cluster version
            var version = hbaseClient.GetVersion();
            Console.WriteLine("The HBase cluster version is " + version);
        }
    }
}
```

I just don't understand how it makes a difference really.

Could you please advice?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you take a thread dump when it hangs, so you can check where exactly it is waiting?

Comment: If my response answered the question, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, you need to run your calls on a background thread.  I ran into this same exact issue.  My calls are consolidated under a single function.  I run that function on a background thread and everything works great.

```
        // POST: api/Vizzini
    [ResponseType(typeof(string))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetResponse(string tweet)
    {
        string s = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return ResponseEngine.GetBestResponse(tweet);
        });
        return Ok(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using blocking synchronous APIs, which won't work in the context of MVC/Web app (due to using wrong async context by default). You need to use async version of the methods. E.g. for GetVersion use GetVersionAsync.